# Using Java's Swing UI to make rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm trying to develop a version of rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock using Java's Swing UI.  I've successfully been able to create frames to select player 1 and player 2 and which rules the game is won by (best 2 out of 3, play till quit, single round), and that run the actual game.  But I'm having trouble looping the game screen if the user want's to play, say best 2 out of 3.  I had originally coded the program just using the console output(Scanner), but now that I am trying to implement the Java Swing UI.  And I can't seem to figure out how to loop round after round without producing all of the game screens at once.

For example, here I have a method I call playRound().  After adding 1 to the round counter, this method constructs `class GameWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener`

```
public static void playRound() {
     ++round; //Simple int counter to keep track of round
     GameWindow oneRound = new GameWindow();
     oneRound.setSize(400, 150);
     oneRound.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     oneRound.setVisible(true);
```

Inside the GameWindow class, I have 5 ActionListeners on the 5 buttons the user can decide to play(rock, paper, scissors, lizard, or spock).  The ActionListeners identify which button was pressed, then triggers the rest of the game logic, as seen below.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String move1 = "";
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == rockBtn) {
            move1 = "rock";
        } else if (source == paperBtn) {
            move1 = "paper";
        } else if (source == scissorsBtn) {
            move1 = "scissors";
        } else if (source == lizardBtn) {
            move1 = "lizard";
        } else {
            move1 = "spock";
        }
        String move2 = Game.p2.move();
        Game.p1.learn(move1, move2);
        Game.p2.learn(move2, move1);
        this.dispose();
        Game.score(move1, move2);
    }
```

I'm fully aware that if I use a while loop along the lines of

```
while (round < 3)
    playRound();
```

I'm going to get three GameWindows to pop up all at once.  Am I stupid, or is there a way to close the window other then `this.dispose()` and get a new one to trigger/open so the user can play again?

Sorry if this is very sophomoric, but I've been scouring JavaDocs trying to learn the answer.  The closest thing I can figure out is that I'm looking for a `WindowEvent`, but I'm not sure where to place the listener for it, or what action I would need it to trigger.  If you just tell me I'm an idiot, I'll go bury my head in the sand and be done with it, but any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One issue you're bagging your ahead against is the use of multiple frames, this is going to not only annoy you, but also the players.  A better solution would be to start with seperate `JPanel` for each major view and then use a `CardLayout` to switch between them.  Your `GameWindow` would then need to know how many rounds are to be played and only switch back to the previous/next panels when that has been achieved

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was starting to consider that approach a few hours ago.  But the user would still need to "interact" with the GameWindow the same number of times weather its a new frame or the same frame.  Thanks for the advice, I'll take a harder look

Comment: Yes, so you need to know how many times the player wants to try (ie best of 2 out 3).  Then each "round" you increment a counter and check it, based on the number of rounds and wins, you make a decision about what to do.  But you do this as part of the `ActionListener` - which becomes your pseudo "loop" of sorts

Comment: @MadProgrammer So what your saying is once I knew how many rounds the user wanted to play, I would then add that many cards to the container and bing-bang,-boom the same Frame repeats itself the specified number of times?

Comment: Me, personally, I'd use a single frame/panel and simple repeat over the same instance

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you want to have three rounds, each time redoing the same logic but keeping the score as a "global variable" for the three rounds, giving user the opportunity to restart again or close entire application after the three rounds are completed.

I'll give you a pratical idea of how I'd make this implemented:

I suggest you to move main coordination logic in a main method, and keep the rest as you posted, with a little modifications.

You can just make your playRound() method returning a ResultDTO object instead of void; this DTO can be a simple POJO object containing all the variables representing the data you want to globally maintain (for example in a `ResultDTO[]` array with 3 elements, filling one position for each round), filling it in the *playMethod()*'s logic and managing the return in an external caller main method. After the three rounds you can just check for result in the main method, print out a dialog showing the results you want to show, and then ask user a yes or no option with JOptionChooser. If user wants to play again, just repeat this whole logic, in the other case you can call System.exit(0) to close application or do whatever you want first (save a file with memory data, print a goodbye message, and so on, it depends on your imagination and how you want to implement this, just be creative).

To ensure your application will not close at the end of a round, you can use `oneRound.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` to avoid application exiting when calling dispose() on your frame.